# Inputing array value MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I have two arrays,

```
A = [23 Nan 45 Nan Nan 67 50 100 110] and B = [24 49 70 71 72 90 100 120 109]
```

`NaN` denotes some gap. I want to place the element of matrix B in the same location in A where it is `NaN`. For example, in array A 2nd position there is a gap, I want to put value 49 from matrix B into that position in array A. So the resulting A matrix becomes

```
A = [23 49 45 71 72 67 50 100 110]
```

Let me know how I can code it in MATLAB. Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure how you have a string (`x`) in a numeric array in Matlab.

Comment: that is only to show missing value. It's a null. Instead of NaN, I put x in that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easily using array indexing.

```
A = [23 NaN 45 NaN NaN 67 50 100 110]
B = [24 49 70 71 72 90 100 120 109]
all_nans = isnan(A)
A(all_nans) = B(all_nans)
```

Giving:

```
A =

    23    49    45    71    72    67    50   100   110
```

`all_nans` contains the indices of all the `NaNs` and the next step basically does the required replacement.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while you can also do `A(isnan(A)) = B(isnan(A))`, you can _not_ do `A(A == NaN) = B(A == NaN)` like you would be able to do with `-1` (or any other number), since `NaN` does not equal `NaN`.